# VMWare Server problem

Tags: vmware-server

[Here](http://pastebin.com/iBRibJNb) is the output from hostd.log on a VMWare server, sitting on top of CentOS.  VM's running on this machine are shutting down sporadically - maybe one every 24 hours?  Can anyone make any sense from the log file?

Versions:  VMware server 2.0.1
Centos 4.8

Guest operating systems that have crashed so far are Windows XP & Centos 5.4.

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you for memory? This can happen if you run out.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Load on the host is high, here's a quick copy paste of the memory available & used.  

Mem:   8053316k total,  7134768k used,   

There is always plenty of swap available though,

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Is there anything in the rest of the logging that mentions a 'Signal 6'? If so, check this out: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/242151?tstart=0 (not CentOS but poss. related. Core of it seems to be a disk controller incompatibility). You may alternatively be hitting this: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3884

Comment: I have indeed found some Signal 6 errors, thanks researching that more now.

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance I would tell there is something wrong with your data partition (/data/data4).
What kind of storage are you using? local disks, raid, nfs?
Do you have any snapshots created for the vm's?

If possible try to enable verbose logging somehow. I didn't find any VMware KB for the VMware Server 2 but there should be a configuration file in /etc or /opt.

As always the question: why are you using VMware Server and not VMware ESXi? VMware Server 2 is not under development anymore and it's pretty slow if you compare it to ESXi.

greetings
grub

Comment: Hi Grub,

Cheers for the reply - just settling into a new role, will be migrating them over to ESXi or Xen in due course.  

Its local disks, non-raided.  No snapshots.  

Ill try to increase the logging and check for any disk errors around the times of the shutdowns.

Cheers,
Dave